# How to get page width and height in pixels in JavaScript when using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, wkhtmltopdf

I am doing the following to generate a PDF from HTML:

```
wkhtmltopdf --grayscale --page-height 10in --page-width 8in index.html index.pdf
```

I have this HTML structure:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      .page {
        page-break-after: always;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='page'>asdf</div>
    <div class='page'>hkl</div>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        var p = document.querySelector('.page')

        var W = p.offsetWidth
        var H = p.offsetHeight
        
        document.body.innerHTML = 'W:' + W + 'H:' + H
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am essentially trying to find a way to measure the dimensions of a "page" (not the body or some regular element). So I've added 2 pages so I can make sure that the `page-break-after` CSS property hopefully takes effect. The final output (if you comment out the `document.body.innerHTML = ...` part) looks like it's divided into pages. But when I log it like the above example shows (super hacky, don't know how to `console.log` in `wkhtmltopdf`), it says:

```
W:0 H:0
```

Why does it say that? How do I get the measurements of a generic "page"? I would like to get the page dimensions so I can calculate the number of characters that can fit on a line given a font size, or the number of lines that can fit on a page given line height. But I can't do that without first knowing how to get the page dimensions.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2419

Comment: Note that wkhtmltopdf uses a *very* old version of chrome, so it is somehow normal for some stuff to work different or not work at all. [Chrome-headless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#create_a_pdf_dom) now has a command line option to generate PDF, you may want to give that a try: chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf https://myurl.com